# How can I make a Mouse Event persist through closing an NSPopover?

Tags: cocoa, mouseevent, nspopover

I have a `NSPopover` that opens, and if the user clicks somewhere else in the app, the popover closes.

But the problem is that currently that `mouseDown` event is consumed during the popover-closing process.

Is it possible to still have that `mouseDown` event go through to the application, but also close the popover?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, so we changed to using `NSPopoverBehaviorSemitransient` for the behavior type. It no longer steals the `mouseDown:` and we just added some extra cases for closing the popover manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the `window`s `contentViewController`s `view` object. 
I did this in the Storyboard file.

In there, implement the `mouseDown()` method. In there, you can create a notification which can be received at a point in your project where you need to know about the mouse event.

As the 'root view' captures almost all `mouseDown()` events, you have to filter them in order to only respond to the notification when the popover is displayed.

Don't forget to call `super.mouseDown()` at the end of your implementation.